# Prevent alias with `find` from running at login

Tags: bashrc, alias

How do I make an `alias` in `.bashrc` with sub-commands?

Right now I have:

```
alias pngc="for file in \`find \$1 -name \"*.png\"\`; do pngcrush -brute \"\$file\" temp.png; mv -f temp.png \$file; done"
```

If I enter this in a shell, the alias is registered correctly and I can run it correctly. However, if I add this to `.bashrc`, (parts of) it runs at login, which I know because it hangs for a huge amount of time, probably because it's `find`-ing in my entire home directory.

(Not a duplicate of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337965/how-to-stop-bashrc-from-running-sub-command-in-alias-at-startup) or [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128995/why-doesnt-my-command-work-when-aliased))

**Edits based on comments:**

Attempt:

```
alias pngc="for file in ./*.png; do pngcrush -brute \"\$file\" temp.png; mv -f temp.png \$file; done"
```

> Could not find file: ./*.png
>   Could not find file: temp.png

(`temp` is the current directory)

Attempt:

```
alias pngc="for file in ./*.png; do [[ -f \"\$i\" ]] || continue; pngcrush -brute \"\$file\" temp.png; mv -f temp.png \$file; done"
```

Does nothing!

Comment: You should not use patterns like `for file in \`find ... \` ; do ...` anyway, see http://bash.cumulonim.biz/BashPitfalls.html#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: See my additions